# Dragging out a .zip file to download

Tags: javascript, node.js, html, zip, nw.js

I am creating a `.zip` file with `node.js` (using `nw.js`), then sending the path to the generated file to the front-end. I want the user to be able to drag the HTML element from the `nw.js` window to his desktop and change it to the `.zip` file on drop (checkout a simple example with another file type [here](http://thingsinjars.com/post/440/create-a-draggable-file-on-the-fly-with-js/)).

I know I can use the `dataTransfer` property and set the data type to `application/zip`, but I don't know how to send the `.zip` file data with this method.

```
React = require "react"

module.exports = React.createClass
    onDragStart : ( event ) ->
        event.dataTransfer.setData "application/zip:#{@props.path}"

    render : ->
        <div draggable="true" onDragStart={@onDragStart}>Download</div>
```

I guess I should create a stream for the `.zip` file but I have no idea how. I have access to the `fs` module, even on the "client" side, so there are no limits. Any thoughts of how can I achieve that effect?

Comment: Generally it works the other way around, you drag files into the window, not out of it. This is certainly doable natively, but not sure nw.js can do it?

Comment: If we can achieve it in any browser with several mime types like `text/html`, `image/png` [...] (and even fonts files), I guess it should somehow work with `application/zip`. And if a browser is able to do that, then I guess it should work in `nw.js` as it is based on Chromium, nah?

Comment: Well, yes, if you can do it in Chrome, you should be able to do it in Node-Webkit as well, and you probably can do it in Chrome? I'll have to test this, but I think you'd need a draggable anchor with the URL, and not just a stream.

Comment: I just took an example from a [how-to](http://www.thecssninja.com/html5/gmail-dragout), and it worked fine with a pdf, but couldn't get it working with a zip file. It seems to work with zip file in Gmail, so it's possible, if one just figures out how.

Comment: I guess it is not working because it's a local file. I will try to create a local server using node.js and try to download the file from here, but it's kinda hacky and there's probably a better solution.

Answer (score 0):

I figured out how to make it work. It was not working because I was trying to download a local file, so I created a temporary HTTP Server which returns the `.zip` file on every request with the MIME type set to `application/zip`. Then I just have to set the data transfer URL to `http://localhost:3000` and voila.

Here's the code:

```
fs      = require "fs"
http    = require "http"
React   = require "react"

module.exports = React.createClass
    componentWillMount : ->
        index  = fs.readFileSync @props.path
        server = http.createServer ( request, response ) =>
            response.writeHead 200, { "Content-Type" : "application/zip" }
            response.end index

        server.listen 3000

    onRequestDownload : ( event ) ->
        event.dataTransfer.setData "DownloadURL", "application/zip:FileName.zip:http://localhost:3000"

    render : ->
        <div className="view download">
            <div className="download-item" draggable="true" onDragStart={@onRequestDownload}>Download</div>
        </div>
```